# Does there exist an open dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure zero?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I know an example for finite lebesgue measure for an open dense set, but not for zero measure.
Otherwise can we prove that no such set exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Any open subset $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, dense or not, contains a small interval $(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon)$ and therefore has positive Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Also worth mentioning here that any open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ *is* Lebesgue measurable. Alternatively, even without that fact, any set containing a set of positive measure cannot have measure zero.